# Filter SQL Server XML by Attribute and return all matching attribute value for elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have the following XML:

```
<Games>
  <Game>
    <Place City="LAS" State="NV" />
    <Place City="ATL" State="GA" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="166" Description="Demons v3" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="171" Description="Race v4" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="162" Description="Doom" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="575" Description="Pac-man" />
    <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="167" Description="Demons v3" />
    <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="170" Description="Race v4" />
    <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="163" Description="Doom" />
    <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="576" Description="Pac-man" />
  </Game>
  <Game>
    <Place City="NYC" State="NY" />
    <Place City="ATL" State="GA" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="166" Description="Grand Thft Auto V" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="171" Description="Red Dead Redemption" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="162" Description="Super Mario Brothers 3" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="575" Description="Game Controller" />
    <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="167" Description="Grand Thft Auto V" />
    <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="170" Description="Red Dead Redemption" />
    <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="163" Description="Super Mario Brothers 3" />
    <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="576" Description="Game Controller" />
  </Game>
  <Game>
    <Place City="MIA" State="FL" />
    <Place City="LAS" State="NV" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="349" Description="Demons v3" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="350" Description="Race v4" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="346" Description="Doom" />
    <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="579" Description="Pac-man" />
    <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="167" Description="Grand Theft Auto V" />
    <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="170" Description="Red Dead Redemption" />
    <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="163" Description="Super Mario Brothers 3" />
    <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="576" Description="Game Controller" />
  </Game>
</Games>
```

I am having difficulty filtering and returning the desired information using SQL.  What I'm looking to accomplish is to filter using the `<Place>` element's attributes: `<city>` and `<state>` to return a complete list of `<Store>` attributes IDs:

For example:

```
SELECT G.S.Store_ID AS Store
,      G.S.Price_ID AS Price
FROM @xml.nodes('') G(S)
WHERE City="NYC" AND State="NY"
```

should return:

```
Store #    Price #
========   ========
12         166
12         171
12         162
12         575 
13         167                   
13         170                   
13         163                                                
13         576
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<Games>
    <Game>
        <Place City="LAS" State="NV"/>
        <Place City="ATL" State="GA"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="166" Description="Demons v3"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="171" Description="Race v4"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="162" Description="Doom"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="575" Description="Pac-man"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="167" Description="Demons v3"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="170" Description="Race v4"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="163" Description="Doom"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="576" Description="Pac-man"/>
    </Game>
    <Game>
        <Place City="NYC" State="NY"/>
        <Place City="ATL" State="GA"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="166" Description="Grand Thft Auto V"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="171" Description="Red Dead Redemption"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="162" Description="Super Mario Brothers 3"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="575" Description="Game Controller"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="167" Description="Grand Thft Auto V"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="170" Description="Red Dead Redemption"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="163" Description="Super Mario Brothers 3"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="576" Description="Game Controller"/>
    </Game>
    <Game>
        <Place City="MIA" State="FL"/>
        <Place City="LAS" State="NV"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="349" Description="Demons v3"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="350" Description="Race v4"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="346" Description="Doom"/>
        <Store Store_ID="12" Price_ID="579" Description="Pac-man"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="167" Description="Grand Theft Auto V"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="170" Description="Red Dead Redemption"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="163" Description="Super Mario Brothers 3"/>
        <Store Store_ID="13" Price_ID="576" Description="Game Controller"/>
    </Game>
</Games>';

SELECT c.value('@Store_ID', 'INT') AS Store_ID
    , c.value('@Price_ID', 'INT') AS Price_ID
FROM @xml.nodes('/Games/Game[Place[@City="NYC" and @State="NY"]]/Store') AS t(c)
```

**Output**

```
+----------+----------+
| Store_ID | Price_ID |
+----------+----------+
|       12 |      166 |
|       12 |      171 |
|       12 |      162 |
|       12 |      575 |
|       13 |      167 |
|       13 |      170 |
|       13 |      163 |
|       13 |      576 |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0